# a function (which requires parameters) as arguments of another function

Tags: javascript, function

I have been using functions as parameters. Now I need to pass a function A which requires parameters x generated by function B. I can do that too. by calling A in B with the parameters.

But my problem is, my function B accepts any kind of function, and it is not fixed. It may take function C also which requires parameter y or some function D that does not need any parameter.

Is this possible?

```
function B(done_function){
  //some task generate some value
  done_function(); 
}
function B(done_function){
 //some task generate some value including args
 done_function(args); 
}
```

How can I make A, C and D functions execute with their arguments.

The top two examples won't work.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem a bit more? Does function `B` have anything that it generates that it needs to pass to the callback? Note how I worded the question. I'm asking if function `B` wants to pass anything to the callback, not what arguments the callback expect

Comment: Yes, function B generates some information, which i need to pass in the done_functions. But A,C and other functions need different types of parameter (from generated information of B).
I could have use switch case, but that is not efficient because i have a lot functions with different parameters (like A,C)

Comment: Sounds like a bad design. How can this mythical function B know when and what to pass to its function parameter? Either it knows what it needs to do to generate the functions' arguments, in which case just do that and pass them as you would to any function, or it doesn't, in which case your function B is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to handle this is to ignore it. Function `B` should simply not care about how other functions accept arguments. Instead it should **only** provide a standard and well documented interface to it's callback:

```
function B (done_function) {
  // do some stuff to generate result
  done_function(result);
}
```

Or if function `B` can possibly generate errors asynchronously then it should do `done_function(err, result)`. Notice that all libraries do this. They don't care how you write your functions.

Now, how to pass various types of functions to `B`? Just wrap them around another function. For example, say you need to pass the result of `B` to a logger function and you need to pass a variable specifying the name of the file to log to. Just do this:

```
B(function(result) {
    logToFile(debugLogFile, result);
});
```

Say for example you need to modify the result because the function you want to pass it to expect it to be in a specific format. Just do something like this:

```
B(function(result) {
    var x = {
        some_parameter: something,
        result: result
    };
    doSomethingElse(x);
});
```

There is no scenario where function `B` needs to be aware of how you want to process the result it generates. It's you, the programmer, who is responsible to convert the result of function `B` appropriately before doing further processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the functions [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method:

```
function B(done_function){
    //some task generate some value including args
    done_function.call(done_function, args); 
}
```

[example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szs3Lekh/)

Comment: May b i was unable to make you understand the question.
my done_function and args are not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let *B* call the callback with a single object as argument, which contains all information:

```
function B(done_function){
    //some task generating some values, including args, for example:
    var args = {
        status: 3,
        code: 'DEC',
        location: 'Atlantic',
        date: new Date('2017-01-01')
    }
    done_function(args);
}
```

Using [ES6 destructuring in function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Pulling_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter), you can filter out the information you need:

Function *A* could look like this:

```
function A({status}) {
    console.log('status is ' + status);
}
B(A);
```

In the same way, *C* could look like this:

```
function C({code, date}) {
    console.log('code is ' + code + ' on ' + date);
}
B(C);
```

Of course, ES6 destructuring is just a nice shortcut syntax, as you can do it also like this:

```
function A(response) {
    console.log('status is ' + response.status);
}
B(A);
```

#### Alternative: use function's `length` property

If the distinction between different kinds of callbacks can be made on the basis of the number of parameters that are defined for them, then you could use the `length` property like this:

```js
function B(done) {
    var code = 'DEC';
    var status = 1;
    var location = 'Atlantic';
    var date = new Date('2017-01-01');
    switch (done.length) {
    case 1: 
        done(status);
        break;
    case 2:
        done(location, date);
        break;
    default:
        done(code, status, location, date);
    }
}

function A(status) {
    console.log('status = ' + status);
}

function C(location, date) {
    console.log('location = ' + location + ' on ' + date.toDateString());
}

B(A);
B(C);
```

Note the [specific rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) that apply for the `length` property's value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! both of you gave the right answer i questioned.

Comment: Although the answers are quite different. The other answer maintains that *there is no scenario where function B needs to be aware of how you want to process the result it generates*. This is not an opinion that is shared by everyone. For instance, the Jasmine test suite deals differently with a test callback function [when it has the *done* parameter](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support). That is where the `length` solution kicks in.